# How to find the Lie Algebra from a matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra

how do I find the Lie algebra of this matrix group using the definition of the matrix Lie algebra:

$$\begin{equation} A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\qquad a,b,c \in R\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 2):

Denote the lie group by $G$. The Lie algebra is the tangent space of the Lie group at the identity. Hence, to find the elements of the Lie algebra we consider paths in $G$ which go through the identity. Specifically, let $\gamma : [0,1] \to G$ be a differentiable function such that $\gamma(0) = I_3$, the identity matrix. Then we have
$$\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & f(t) & g(t)\\
0 & 1 & h(t)\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where
$$f(0)=g(0)=h(0)=0 $$

The derivative at $t=0$ is then

$$\gamma'(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & f'(0) & g'(0)\\
0 & 0 & h'(0)\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The values of $f'(0),g'(0),h'(0)$ can be any real number and so the lie algebra is given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x & y\\
0 & 0 & z\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \text{ for } x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Could this be done from the definition of a matrix lie group? ie. by expanding the exponential matrix?

Comment: @kgorp what definition of a matrix lie group are you working with? The one I'm familiar with is that its a subgroup of $GL_n$ which is a smooth manifold (more or less)

Comment: @kgorp: The matrix exponential is used for going in the other direction, from Lie algebra to Lie group.